# Can you control brightness on two monitors simultaneously via the brightness key?

Tags: display

I have two Thunderbolt monitors daisy chained together and when I press down on the brightness key (<kbd>F1</kbd>/<kbd>F2</kbd>) it only dims the brightness / ups it only on one monitor. Is there a way so that when the brightness hotkey is pressed it can control both the monitors without having to open settings to control the other monitor?

Thanks.

Comment: It's not a solution, but instead of opening the panel you can use control + F1/F2 to adjust the brightness on the secondary monitor.

Comment: Take a look in Better Touch Tool. I remember that somewhere there was an option to create shortcuts to change brightness on external monitors. This may work also with multiple monitors in one command, if setup properly...

Comment: @Matteo Thanks! I didn't know you could do that. This is suffice solution! :D

Comment: @Monstr92 OK I posted it as an answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This will not allow you to change them simultaneously but you can use

- <kbd>F1</kbd> or <kbd>F2</kbd> for the main display and
- <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> or <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> for the secondary display

As an addition you can also modify the brightness in smaller steps (1/4) by pressing <kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd> with both combinations.