# Is there a list of monitors whose brightness can be controlled by the keyboard in macOS?

Tags: macos, display

I know Apple's Studio Display and LG UltraFine 24MD4kL support [keyboard controls of display backlight / brightness](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/110397/5472).  I would like to be able to look for other display options.

I change the brightness up and down like 100 times a day, so the monitor physical button is a no-go for me.

Even better than a list is there a technical way to test for this integration on macOS or is it all done by drivers Apple embeds in the system?